# Start an executable on a remote station

Tags: powershell, executable

I have a executable that resides on a remote station that I am trying to run from a central server, but running into issues.  I am able to stop the Process on the remote station from the server using

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $name {Stop-Process -Name "ProcessName"
```

But when I try and run the executable, using

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $Args Start-Process "C:\Process\Process.exe"
```

it returns an error

> This command cannot be run due to the error: The system cannot find the file

I have tried many variations of `Invoke-Command`, `Start-Process`, along with specifying the UNC path using the `$name` variable, but it will not run the executable stored on the remote computer.

Comment: Both of your sample commands are broken, and the error message is not a PowerShell error. Please create a [mcve], test-run *that* code to make sure it exposes the problem you're asking about, then [edit] your question and copy/paste *that* code and the complete error thrown by that code. Do not fabricate things. Do not type from memory.

Answer (score 0):

You should run it like this:

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $name -ScriptBlock {
    Set-Location c:\path\to\exe
    FileName.exe /switch 1 /switch 2
}
```

You don’t need to use `Start-Process`. Just call the file and it should start execution.

Comment: When I run this, I get a response back:  *The term 'DrAgent.exe' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (DrAgent.exe:String) [], Command 
   NotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
    + PSComputerName        : PACS-140-570*

I can run previous commands in the same PS script that connect to this same computer, and stop multiple processes.

Comment: Try .\filename.exe, or perhaps instead of Set-Location, do cmd /c c:\full\path\filename.exe